# Получить часть предложения после разделителя

Tags: python

Входые данные :`mail:76be2863c7d9aa65b72d1aa8f7c358c7`.
Нужно получить ту часть строки , которая после разделителя `:`.
Пытался сделать через  `str.split(':')` - выводит в JSON .

Comment: Не json, а самый обычный банальный плоский список.

Answer (score 3):

```
s = "mail:76be2863c7d9aa65b72d1aa8f7c358c7"
s.split (':')[1]
'76be2863c7d9aa65b72d1aa8f7c358c7'
```